# window.open() is blocked by browser when is called from promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have code like this:

```
window.open('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/',
'_blank',
'width=700,height=500,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0,modal=yes');
```

This works fine when is called from any place of code, but when I use it in promise (see below), it is always blocked by browser. Any suggestions?

```
action().success(function (r) {
  // window.open(...);
}
```

Promises are from angular.

Comment: The other two answers are better and should be accepted in place of the one that says you can't do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The promise fires in response to you getting the HTTP response back from the Ajax request. That isn't a user triggered event, so popups are blocked. Use the window the user gives you instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 20):

```
            var newTab = $window.open('', '_blank');
        promise
            .then(function () {
                var url = '...';
                newTab.location.href = url;
            });
```

Answer (score 17):

The solution I use to this problem is to

1. immediately open the window and keep a reference (when it's legal, that is in the event handler)
2. launch the asynchronous operation
3. then, in the promise, use the window you opened and fill it (you may use `win.location`)

Comment: What if I don't know before hand if I'll need to open a the popup? As in: `action().then(doWindowOpenThing).catch(doSomethingElseThatDoesntOpenAPopup)`

So I can't open a window before hand (to keep its reference, etc) if later on I won't be using it, right?

Comment: @luiz A hacky solution might be to open that window and close it if it's not necessary. But I would look for a ergonomics based workaround, for example doing the query which might fail then showing a dialog "the thing worked, do you want to see the result in a new window ?".