# Open window inside promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise, q

We are using a promise lib Q and we encounter the following issue.
[window.open() is blocked by browser when is called from promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287940/window-open-is-blocked-by-browser-when-is-called-from-promise)

We try to open the window before the promise mechanism  has started and this is working but the issue is that when a new tab is opened (and get the focus) all the browser resources are refer to the new tab and the logic is still done in the first tab which cause to bad performance.

There is other way to handle this maybe with event when the promise finished and then catch this event and open new window.

**Update**

What does it mean "all the browser resources are refer to the new tab"
we found interesting behavior :)
We are running application when user click on button, in this case we are open new tab and the focus is changed to the new tab and we are waiting to the app to start, this takes about 15 second (until the application actually running).
We did the following test (which is very interesting :) ) and when we click on run application and the new tab is opens we are **immediately** click back to the first tab (which have the buttons)  and by doing this the time is reduce to 4.5 seconds! It seems that the focus change the way that the resources is handled by the browsers.

I'm searching for alternative solutions!

Comment: What does "all the browser resources are refer to the new tab" mean?

Comment: @jfriend00 - its too long :) please see my update ,what do you think and how we can overcome it ?

Comment: We can't help with your code issue without seeing the relevant code.  Do you expect us to guess what the code is?  One wild guess is that Javascript timers in background windows get slowed down while foreground window timers go full speed.  But, since I have no idea what your code does, I have no idea if that is even relevant.

Comment: From the Stack Overflow guidelines: ***Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).***

Comment: @jfriend00 - I dont need a code help since this is already done and working as the link provided and your suggestion to open the window when at the button click which is working but the problem is that that we have in performance and my question is to open the window as suggested is the only way or there is additional ways which we can consider...

Comment: So what is your question, what do you want us to solve? All I can see in your post is a statement that you experienced the same problem as in the linked question. Now do you think there's a different solution?

Comment: @Bergi - I want to know if there is other solution that was suggest like when all the promise process will be finished to raise an event to open window and taking the url from some persistance or someting,what do you think?

Comment: @JhonD - I think I've already explained that there are NO other options that will work from a promise resolution because by definition it is asynchronous and opening a window from an async call (or any non-user action) is blocked these days (because of annoying ad scripts).  So, your answer is there is no other alternative.  If there was, it would be immediately exploited by ad scripts and then would be blocked by the next revisions of the browsers.  You can thank the annoying habits of ad scripts for causing the disabling of some useful features.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is because of a conflict among two policies:

1. By specification, promises execute `.then()` handlers asynchronously (after the current event loop has finished).
2. For usability and security reasons `window.open()` can only be called from a direct user action (during the same event loop processing that was started by a user action or within a short time afterwards from some user action).

Because of #2, you will not be able to open a window from a `.then()` handler of a promise that follows the promise specification.

The usual work-around is to open the window synchronously when the user clicks (before the promise has been resolved) and then to either fill in the content of the window you have already opened when the promise resolves or in error cases to close the window.  This is not ideal, but if asynchronous operations are involved in the opening of a window, there really aren't other choices besides obtaining elevated privileges such as in a browser plugin (not from a normal web page script).

For more detailed help on how to solve specific coding issues with implementing this work-around, you will have to add your actual code to your question and describe the specific problems with it you are running into.

Questions asking for help with specific code must include the code you want help with.

Comment: I think you should move your answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287940/window-open-is-blocked-by-browser-when-is-called-from-promise and we'd close this as a dupe

Comment: @Bergi - this is not the same suggestion which was provided in the answer? I already provided this link but I wonder if there is alternatives ...

Comment: @JhonD: I think this is exactly the same explanation as provided by Quentin and the same solution as suggested by Denys. If you're looking for more alternatives, you should a) explicitly ask for that and b) maybe offer a bounty on the original question instead.

Answer (score 1):

This was my workaround. HTML:

```html
<div id="next_to"></dif>
```

and within the promise

```
.then(() => {
    var url = 'some place ...';
    $("#next_to").bind( "click", function() {
        window.open(url,"_parent");
    };
    $("#next_to").click();
});
```